# How to set latitude and longitude in a leaflet map using SQlite and C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, leaflet

I am building an app that given latitude and longitude from a form, creates a database using C# and SQlite, however I searched many things and non of them helped me in my purpose. What I want is, given a database in SQlite (in C#), put a marker in the map using leaflet, this is, given the coordinates in latitude, longitude, put a marker in the map and exibit.

I use the following generated table:

```
using maps.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace maps.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitCreate : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Locals",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    latitude = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
                    longitude = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Locals", x => x.ID);
                });
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Locals");
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to make the map and put the marker using an script in cshtml as in:

```
<body>

    <div id = "map" style = "width:700px; height:580px"></div>

    <script>


        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        

        var seekPlace = L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
        
    </script>


</body>
```

Does anyone know exactly the procedure for doing this task? Observe also that I am using a MVC model at ASP.NET.